# How to create RESTfull webservice in Zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I am new for zend.i need to create web-service in zend using Zend_Json_Server  with JSON responce. I have define api controller here..

```
<?php
class ApiController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    { }
    public function indexAction()
    { }
    public function restAction()
    {

      // disable layouts and renderers
          $this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender ( true );

          // initialize REST server
          $server = new Zend_Json_Server();
          // set REST service class
          $server->setClass('Test_Return');

          // handle request
          if ('GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
               $server->setTarget('/json-rpc.php')
                       ->setEnvelope(Zend_Json_Server_Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);
                $smd = $server->getServiceMap();

                // Set Dojo compatibility:
               // $smd->setDojoCompatible(true);

                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo $smd;

            }
          $server->handle();
    }
}
?>
```

And Test_Return define in  Library/Test
Test_Return code is here..

```
<?php
class Test_Return {

    public function add($x, $y)
    {
        return $x + $y;
    }
    public function subtract($x, $y)
    {
        return $x - $y;
    }
    public function multiply($x, $y)
    {
        return $x * $y;
    }
      public function divide($x, $y)
    {
        return $x / $y;
    }
} ?>
```

How can call particular expression.

Comment: I would expect the code of the server bootstrap to be in your index.php. I hope that this site [http://www.zendcasts.com/tag/rest/] can help you. I will have a look at it on the evenning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Zend_Json_Server initialization should be in your public/index.php

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH') ||
    define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

defined('APPLICATION_ENV') ||
    define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/libs',
    get_include_path(),
)));



require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

   $application = new Zend_Application(
      APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');


   $application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap();
   // Instantiate server ...
   $server = new Zend_Json_Server();
   include_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/Calculator.php';
   $server->setClass(new Calculator());
   if ('GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
   {
        // Indicate the URL endpoint, and the JSON-RPC version used:
        $server->setTarget('/api/1.0/jsonrpc.php')->setEnvelope(Zend_Json_Server_Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);
        // Grab the SMD
        $smd = $server->getServiceMap();
        // Return the SMD to the client
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $smd;
        return;
   }
   $server->handle();

$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

With curl on the command line you wont see anything ;-). This frustrated me a bit.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"method":"add","x":5,"y":10}' http://zend.rest.server/api/1.0/jsonrpc.php
```

On the browser you can use this [jQuery plugin](https://code.google.com/p/es-search/source/browse/trunk/public/res/js_dev/jquery.zend.jsonrpc.js?r=18)

```
app = jQuery.Zend.jsonrpc({url: '/api/1.0/jsonrpc'});
app.add(5, 5);

{"result":10,"id":"1","jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

You maybe want to follow the steps as describe [here](https://blog.jtclark.ca/2010/05/creating-a-json-rpc-server-with-zend-framework/).

I suggest that you apgrade your version of zend if you can as zend2.X.X has better support for rest services.

Answer (score 1):

As describe in [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.rest.server.html) on your index you create an instance of the zend_rest_server add your methods and run it. The methods should be specified in the url. I sugest you chose zend 2 for better implementation

Comment: I have used this url  but it throws error 
 'XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity'

Comment: try using Zend_Json_Server  http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.json.server.html

Comment: I have try using Zend_Json_Server .Can u suggest me how can call rest apis in the restfull method?.

Comment: {"error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Invalid Request","data":null},"id":null} error in json

Comment: The error mean that you are not passing any parameters. I understand that the method should be pass in the input method by default and the json on the data input. Maybe add a Content-Type="application/json" json on your request headers. It is very hard with out the code but i think the problem is where you make the request